# Are bounties refunded on deleted questions?

Tags: support, bounties, deleted-questions

I've researched here on MSE, but I haven't found a definitive answer to whether bounties are refunded on deleted questions. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067), bounties are not refundable. Does this also apply to deleted questions, or does it only apply to non-deleted posts?

Comment: The section in the duplicate which is titled "What happens if a question where I awarded a bounty later gets deleted or migrated?" appears relevant.